# How do we prove an open set?

Tags: calculus

The question is prove or disprove that $$U=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x\in (-1,1), \ y=0\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$$ is an open set.

I have the answer, which is:
$U$ is not open because $(\epsilon/2,\epsilon/2)\in B_\epsilon(0,0)$, but $(\epsilon/2 ,\epsilon/2)$ ∉$U$

I don't really get the concept of open sets and how to prove they are open.
Can anyone explain to me why that is the answer?

Comment: What is the definition of "open" that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

The set is not open because if you draw a disc around the origin $(0,0)$ (note that the origin is in the set $U$), no matter how small the circle is, as long as the radius is positive, it is not contained inside the set $U$.

Comment: OK, thanks! Then may I ask you where (ϵ/2) comes from?

Comment: First we draw a ball with size $\epsilon$ about the origin. $(\epsilon/2, \epsilon/2)$ is a point in the ball but this point is not in the set $U$. You can choose another point in the set to repeat the argument. it need not be that point.